# How do I replace main Woocommerce shop page with custom page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I built a custom page with just a product table displayed. I wish to use this as the main page (root url) of the website. How do I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you set that page as the as the [static front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a [Static Homepage](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) like @helgatheviking mentioned in the Comments.

Your best-friend for developing a WordPress site is the [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/)